# Can’t bind to “cdkDropListData” since it isn’t a known property of ‘div’.?

Tags: angular, angularjs, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk, angular-dragdrop

I’m trying to use Drag-Drop evet in Angular with cdk but when I tried to import codes to my proects (imports etc.) the terminal says Can’t bind to “cdkDropListData” since it isn’t a known property of ‘div’. What is solution of this?

imported cdk from angular core

Comment: You should import in module:`import {DragDropModule} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop'; `

Comment: I tried but it doesnt work

Comment: be sure that you has a cdkDropList, not only a div. For this you need add the directive cdkDropList to your div to promotionate your "div" to a "cdkDropList": `<div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="variable or value">`

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem
And by adding `cdkDropList` to the **module** this was **fixed**